# Conventions for 'import ... as'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Typically, one uses `import numpy as np` to import the module numpy.

Are there general conventions for naming?

What about other modules, in particular from scientific computing like `scipy`, `sympy` and `pylab` or submodules like `scipy.sparse`.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/general.html

Comment: As an Englishman, you'll often find `import math as maths` in my code. Stops me mistyping it all of the time.

Comment: I'm importing a particular file `import routers.auth.schemas as ...`. What should I replace the `...` as - `AuthSchemas` or `auth_schemas`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SciPy recommends `import scipy as sp` in [its documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/general.html), though personally I find that rather useless since it only gives you access to re-exported NumPy functionality, not anything that SciPy adds to that. I find myself doing `import scipy.sparse as sp` much more often, but then I use that module heavily. Also

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
```

You might encounter more of these as you start using more libraries. There's no registry or anything for these shorthands and you're free to invent new ones as you see fit. There's also no general convention except that `import lln as library_with_a_long_name` obviously won't occur very often.

Aside from these shorthands, there's a habit among Python 2.x programmers to do things like

```
# Try to import the C implementation of StringIO; if that doesn't work
# (e.g. in IronPython or Jython), import the pure Python version.
# Make sure the imported module is called StringIO locally.
try:
    import cStringIO as StringIO
except ImportError:
    import StringIO
```

Python 3.x is putting an end to this, though, because it no longer offers partial C implementations of `StringIO`, `pickle`, etc.

Comment: As per docs, "Scipy sub-packages need to be imported separately", i.e. `from scipy import sparse`, which makes more sense then `import scipy.sparse as sp`, especially as scipy is recommended to be imported under `sp`. So suggesting `scipy.sparse` to be imported under `sp` is surely not good recommendation, although you can import modules under any name you want, which is not what OP asked.